# Best way to include js module in any browser

Tags: javascript, module, npm, ecmascript-6, shared-libraries

I have built a large library that I want to include in a different web project. This library manages all of its own dependencies and includes js, css, and html files.

Ideally I would like to wrap as a npm module and just use `import` to include in a Front End project, but according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) its not officially supported by all browsers. I would need some reasonable support in chrome, safari, firefox and IE.

I also dont want to have a requirement for external module loaders. I really just want to download, include and GO.

It seems clunky to download a folder of the library and then use a script tag to reference the entry point file.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Most front-end libraries go the "download, unzip, include the css and js in your html" route. The alternatives are: hosting on a CDN (so you provide URLs to the JS/CSS without downloading them), publishing in bower and/or npm. If your library gains traction you'll probably end up doing all of these and then some, because different developers have different workflows.

Answer (score 0):

The way to support all users is an npm module with both source (what you already have) and a UMD version, which can be consumed by CommonJs and AMD module loaders, as well as via an old school script tag.

What this requires from you is to add a build step and include it's output as part of your module. Webpack is pretty much the standard tool to achieve this nowadays.

Relevant section in webpack docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html